# Is it a good practice to override list() in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

My question is all in the title.

I am using DRF mixins and I would like to know if I can override method `list()` in class `ListModelMixin`. I need to add some computed information to my data.

The code source is as below and you can find it [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a common practice, if you need any different behavior.

This practice is also mentioned in the DRF documentation. So, you can safely do it.
(See: [examples](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#examples) )